# How to use a model or module in both frontend and backend

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Can any one guide me how to use for model in both frontend and backend in Yii2 advanced template.

Secondly what should I do if I want to use a module in both frontend and backend sides?

I have already tried to put model in common. But I am unable to access it. I am new to yii2 so detailed guide will be helpful.

Comment: Please learn how to ask good questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also example of what you have tried will be useful too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general it doesn't matter where you place it.

But in *advanced template* **common** folder exists exactly for these purposes.

For example, create `User` model and place it in `common\models` folder:

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    ...
}
```

No special configuration required.

Then you can use it like that:

```
use common\models\User;

User::find()->...
```

or

```
common\models\User::find()->...
```

The same with module, just place its content in `common\modules\users` for example. Common folder is for commonly used classes.

Also check official PHP documentation for [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Answer (score 3):

You can make Models and Controllers and Views reusable via Modules approach by placing the module in common folder.
Step by step guide is below:

1. Make module "`order`" in any of the end (backend or frontend)
2. Create a new folder "`modules`" in common and ***cut/paste*** the order module from backend/frontend into this new "`modules`" folder
3. Open Module.php and rename the namespace to "`common\modules\order`" and rename the `$controllerNamespace` variable as well like this

   public $controllerNamespace = 'common\modules\order\controllers';
4. Rename the namespace of DefaultController.php class to "`common\modules\order`"
5. Add this new module in config files (`config/main.php`) of both frontend and backend like this

   > ```
   > 'modules' => [
   >         'order' => [
   >             'class' => 'common\modules\order\Module',
   >         ],
   >     ],
   >     'components' => [
   > .
   > .
   > .
   > ```
6. Now you can access the reusable order module from both frontend and backend like this

> ```
> mysite/frontend/web/index.php?r=order
> mysite/backend/web/index.php?r=order
> ```